# Launch Gmail contextual gadgets on G Suite Market Place

Tags: google-workspace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I want to add my existing Gmail contextual gadgets to G Suite Market Place as "Works with Gmail". can anybody help me which step should I follow. I have manifest.xml. for G suite it required manifest.json. please help me. thanks in advance!